# how to call a function that created in DLL file to when clicked Button in c#?

Tags: c#, dll

I created a function which insert values to database in a DLL file. How to call that function by clicking a button?
DLL class name is `DBconnection`

**Code**

```
private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connstr = "Data Source=DESKTOP-QPC780F;Initial Catalog=db_evernote;Integrated Security=True";
    DBconnection.DBconnection db = new DBconnection.DBconnection(connstr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference to the DLL you have created.

In the button click event, Create an object to the class `DBconnection dbConnection = new DBconnection(connectionstring)`

Call the method by using the object `dbConnection.insertdata()`

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple.reference your DLL in the page you  want to use it.

```
using DBconnection;
```

Then on the button click call the function in that class

```
private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connstr = "Data Source=DESKTOP-QPC780F;Initial Catalog=db_evernote;Integrated Security=True";
    DBconnection.DBconnection db = new DBconnection.DBconnection(connstr);
    db.InsertData("Pass your Data object");
```

}